# C++ Constructor with fixed length array as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I'm sure this is a duplicate but everything I've seen has explained how to dynamically allocate memory for an array. I have a fixed length of an array and I just want to put it in a wrapper struct for ease of reference. Here's the bare bones code:

HEADER FILE

```
#ifndef BOARD_T_H
#define BOARD_T_H
#include <iostream>
struct board_t {
    board_t();
    /* I've tried explicitly assigning length b[16] and just declaring
    * b[]. Neither seem to work.
    ------------------------v                     */                      
    board_t(unsigned int b[16]);
    board_t(board_t& other);
    unsigned int values[16];
};

#endif
```

CPP FILE

```
#include "board_t.hpp"
board_t::board_t(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) values[i] = 0;
}

board_t::board_t(unsigned int b[16]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        values[i] = b[i];
    }
}
board_t::board_t(board_t& other) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) this->values[i] = other.values[i];
}
```

TEST FILE

```
#include "board_t.hpp"

int main(){
    unsigned int arr[16]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i ) arr[i] = i;
    board_t b = board_t(arr);
}
```

COMPILE ERRORS

```
$ g++ test.cpp include/board_t.cpp -o test.out
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘board_t::board_t(unsigned int [16])’
  board_t b = board_t(arr);
                         ^
test.cpp:6:25: note: candidates are:
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
include/board_t.hpp:6:2: note: board_t::board_t(board_t&)
  board_t(board_t& other);
  ^
include/board_t.hpp:6:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘unsigned int [16]’ to ‘board_t&’
include/board_t.hpp:5:2: note: board_t::board_t()
  board_t();
  ^
include/board_t.hpp:5:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

I know there are ways (like using std::array or boost etc) but this is really bugging me -- I just have to know how to get this to work!

Sorry again if this is super obvious. I try not to pollute SE with duplicates but sometimes I just can't help myself ;)

Comment: You probably want just `board_t b(arr);` in the test file.

Comment: Yup, that was stupid. Sorry guys, waste of everyones time!

Comment: In C++, the compiler is vastly more "intelligent" than any human being, so all errors humans make are "stupid" :)

Comment: _" I have a fixed length of an array and I just want to put it in a wrapper struct for ease of reference."_ You mean, like `std::array`?

Comment: NB this has nothing to do with arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just do

```
board_t b(arr);
```

not

```
board_t b = board_t(arr);
```

The reasoning is the following. When you write

```
board_t b = board_t(arr);
```

the compiler creates a temporary instance and then tries to initialize **b** with the copy-construtor, taking your temporary as the argument. However, your temporary is an r-value. Your copy-constructor is declared as

```
board_t(board_t& board);
```

That is, taking in a reference to a variable of type board_t. But, r-values can't be passed as reference parameters. R-values can however be passed to **const** references. Meaning, if you write

```
board_t(const board_t& board);
```

Then your code will work fine.

Remark: Even though in theory a temporary will be created as your code is, most compilers will optimize away the temporary and just create **b** on the spot, without ever creating a temporary. Lookup copy-elision if you're interested.

Comment: Hah, you not only caught the (stupid) bug in my test program which was a copy ans paste error but you solved the problem that I was TRYING to convey. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define correctly the copy constructor:

```
board_t(board_t const& other);
                ^^^^^
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4c384582070d2b9)